# Creating piecharts with tm_bubbles() from tmap package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, tmap

I want to create a piechart using tm_bubbles(), or more generally, using the tmap package in R.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
library(tmap)
library(spData)
us_states_map = tm_shape(st_transform(us_states,2163)) + tm_polygons() + 
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
us_states_map + tm_shape(gbs.sf) +
  tm_bubbles(size=c("uninfected",super.haps),labels=c("uninfected",super.haps),
             col=c("gray",brewer.pal(3,"Accent")),style="cat",
             alpha=0.7,scale=2) + 
  tm_legend(legend.position=c("right","bottom"))
```

This creates the following [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhp82.jpg) which places each variable into a different subplot instead of plotting it proportionally into the same bubble (as seen in a piechart) in each location.

I am looking to have just one plot with each bubble representing all 4 colors in a proportional fashion instead.

PS: gbs.sf is a data matrix with the locations for each bubble, total population (here, area of the bubble), and its constituent components ("uninfected", "melissa", etc.) as a numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the third example from the `tm_symbols` help page, which does exactly that. You'll need to create a list of ggplot2 piecharts as grobs, and specify the `shapes` argument of `tm_symbols` with that.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? All I can find is a stacked chart option.